# Ubuntu 17.10 is not running Wayland

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.10, gdm, wayland

I am experiencing some strange problems in Ubuntu 17.10. At the login screen I am missing the small icon that allows changing between X and Wayland. In fact, the default installation is running X and not Wayland (verified by running `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` in terminal, which outputs `x11`).

I also have duplicated processes running, for example two Xorg processes, two gnome-shell processes etc.., one from my user and the other from gdm user, which doubles the memory usage on startup. In order to see the duplicated processes I had to check "All Processes" in System Monitor so that it shows the processes of all users. Screen shots of System Monitor:

[image: Screenshot: System Monitor with xorg]

[image: Screenshot: System Monitor with gnome-shell]

I did this because I found it strange that Ubuntu 17.10 was using 1.2 Gb ram at startup of 4 Gb total. Even Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity only used 800 Mb.

By exploring the virtual terminals with Ctrl+Alt+F1-7 I can see that there is always a gdm session at TTY1. My session is on TTY2. TTY7 outputs some kernel message like this "/dev/sda: clean files blocks", where in previous Ubuntu versions it was supposed to go back to my session.

This is a follow up of [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/77g722/ubuntu_1710_problems/) where I explain that the Ubuntu 17.10 install was a clean install and that I didn't install any Nvidia driver. Previously I was running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Using 1.2GB ram at startup isn't a surprise. It's normal scenario

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered a similar issue to this (gdm3 was unable to launch wayland on my ubuntu 17.10 system) - I resolved it by switching to lightdm.

I was not seeing the duplicate process issues you report, but maybe that will help.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (GDM3 shows only Xorg session) on dual monitor setup. With only one monitor connected the Wayland session was present. From syslog it seems that GDM fail to start on Wayland when there is no monitor defined as primary and fall back to X.

Solution was to setup a display layout in X session and then copy a monitor configuration file from home directory to the GDM configuration directory:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config/
sudo chown gdm:gdm /var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with gdm3 and wayland which lightdm did not solve.

On artful (17.10), I first installed the nvidia-384 proprietary driver. When trying to revert to wayland from xorg (removing nvidia driver), gdm3 would not offer a wayland session.
I had to edit `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and comment out the wayland line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false.
```