# No option to switch between X11 and Wayland on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: xorg, wayland

The way you're supposed to switch between them is using the cog icon on the login screen, but this is what I see:

[image: login screen]

Why do I only have Xorg and why are there two of them? How can I switch to Wayland?

Comment: Not a duplicate, since the solution there is to use the cog icon to switch between them, which is obviously impossible in my situation.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966688/ubuntu-17-10-is-not-running-wayland

Comment: sorry , wrong link

Comment: @pomsky Yeah this seems to be the problem. I thought that the new Nvidia drivers supported Wayland's EGL though.

Comment: nvidia does not support wayland yet, they are working on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Should I go ahead and delete the question or do you want to answer it?